# Pass several parameters to NodeJS validation function

Tags: node.js, validation

I have a validation function, that is used to check the content length, in the model.

```
let contentLengthchecker = (content) => {
    if(!content){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(content.length < 5 || content.length > 100){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

So, I put this as a validator field on the model schema like this...

```
const titleValidators = [
    {validator: contentLengthchecker, message: 'Title length must be between 6 to 30 characters'}
];
```

and put that array in the validator field on the model.

```
const adSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true, validate: titleValidators},
    description: {type: String, required: true, validate: descriptionValidators}
});
```

So, now I want make this function little bit **reusable**. So, I'm writing it like this

```
let contentLengthchecker = (content, minLength, maxLength) => {
    if(!content){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(content.length < minLength || content.length > maxLength){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

But, now I'm struggling to pass minLength and maxLenght parameters to it. I have no idea where to put them in the model schema.

So, where to put additional parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const titleValidators = [{
    validator: contentLengthchecker,
    message: 'Title length must be between 6 to 30 characters',
    minLength: 6,
    maxLength: 30
}];


let contentLengthchecker = (content) => {
if(!content){
    return false;
}else{
    if(!this.minLength || !this.maxLength){
        throw 'minLength or maxLength is not specified';
    }
    if(content.length < this.minLength || content.length > this.maxLength){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gives a way to do it. But, what I'm looking for is to pass more parameters to the function... :)